# Can't float a span inside of a div

Tags: jquery, css, css-float, html

**UPDATE 2:**

I can't float a span inside of a div..

```
<div class="noselect" id="teach_create_pageheader">
<span class="teach_create_pageheader_back"></span>
   Step 1
<span class="teach_create_pageheader_forward"></span>
</div>
```

Here's my css. I want them to float left and float to right accordingly.

```
#teach_create_pageheader{
width:880px;
height: 30px;
margin: -10px;
padding-top: 5px;
background-color: gray;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
opacity:0.8;
filter:alpha(opacity=80);
}

.teach_create_pageheader_back{
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.teach_create_pageheader_forward{
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

span {
display: block;
}
```

And I have JQuery making the buttons (as well as others) with this code:

```
(function($){

// Creating the jQuery plugin:
$.fn.sweetPages = function(opts){

// If no options were passed, create an empty opts object
if(!opts) opts = {};

var resultsPerPage = opts.perPage || 3;

// The plugin works best for unordered lists, althugh ols would do just as well:
var ul = this;
var li = ul.find('li');

li.each(function(){
    // Calculating the height of each li element, and storing it with the data method:
    var el = $(this);
    el.data('height',el.outerHeight(true));
});

// Calculating the total number of pages:
var pagesNumber = Math.ceil(li.length/resultsPerPage);

// If the pages are less than two, do nothing:
if(pagesNumber<2) return this;

// Creating the controls div:
var swControls = $('<div class="swControls">');

for(var i=0;i<pagesNumber;i++)
{
    // Slice a portion of the lis, and wrap it in a swPage div:
    li.slice(i*resultsPerPage,(i+1)*resultsPerPage).wrapAll('<div class="swPage" />');

    // Adding a link to the swControls div:
    swControls.append('<a href="" class="swShowPage">'+(i+1)+'</a>');
}

ul.append(swControls);

var maxHeight = 0;
var totalWidth = 0;

var swPage = ul.find('.swPage');
swPage.each(function(){

    // Looping through all the newly created pages:

    var elem = $(this);

    var tmpHeight = 0;
    elem.find('li').each(function(){tmpHeight+=$(this).data('height');});

    if(tmpHeight>maxHeight)
        maxHeight = tmpHeight;

    totalWidth+=elem.outerWidth();

    elem.css('float','left').width(ul.width());
});

swPage.wrapAll('<div class="swSlider" />');

// Setting the height of the ul to the height of the tallest page:
ul.height(maxHeight);

var swSlider = ul.find('.swSlider');
swSlider.append('<div class="clear" />').width(totalWidth);

var hyperLinks = ul.find('a.swShowPage');

hyperLinks.click(function(e){

    // If one of the control links is clicked, slide the swSlider div 
    // (which contains all the pages) and mark it as active:

    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    swSlider.stop().animate({'margin-left':-(parseInt($(this).text())-1)*ul.width()},'slow');
    e.preventDefault();
});

// Mark the first link as active the first time this code runs:
hyperLinks.eq(0).addClass('active');

// Center the control div:
swControls.css({
    'left':'50%',
    'margin-left':-swControls.width()/2
});

return this;

}})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function(){
/* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

// Calling the jQuery plugin and splitting the
// #holder UL into pages of 3 LIs each:

$('#holder').sweetPages({perPage:1});

// The default behaviour of the plugin is to insert the 
// page links in the ul, but we need them in the main container:

var controls = $('.swControls').detach();
controls.appendTo('#main');



function swGotoPage(page){
      $('.swShowPage:contains("' + page + '")').click();
}

var baseFB = '<input type="button" class="swFB" />';
var offset = 'pgOffset';
var active = '.swShowPage.active';

var $pgBack = $(baseFB)
    .attr('id', 'button_back')
    .attr('value', "Back")
    .attr(offset, '-1');

var $pgForward = $(baseFB)
    .attr('id', 'button_forward')
    .attr('value', "Forward")
    .attr(offset, '1');

$.each([$pgBack, $pgForward], function(i,$obj){
    $obj.click(function(){
        var nextPage =  parseInt($(active).text(), 10) + parseInt($(this).attr(offset), 10);
        swGotoPage(nextPage);
    });
});


$($pgForward).addClass("teach_create_backforward");
$($pgBack).addClass("teach_create_backforward");

$('#teach_create_pageheader_back').replaceWith($pgBack);
$('#teach_create_pageheader_forward').replaceWith($pgForward);

});
```

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help + to indent code with four spaces, you can select it and press the `{}` button.

Answer (score 5):

You are using an id selector and a class selector:

```
#teach_create_pageheader_back{   /* ID */
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.teach_create_pageheader_forward{ /* class */
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Maybe one of them is wrong?

Comment: @Jon I need the elements to be on the same line.. I assigned the display: block; to css and it does nothing..

Comment: Downvoter: If you believe there is a problem with the answer, I 'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @JDAudi: If you fix the bad selector for the "forward" span, it does work just fine. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jVvVG/

Comment: -1 @ Jon, it's wrong information. I'm looking for the right info for you but I see my 1 downvote earned you 3 ups.. so I guess you're not too bothered about the correct info ;)

Comment: `float` applies to any element: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-float - floating an element automatically makes it into a block so there's no need to add `display: block`

Comment: @Jon the elements in the back & forward span is generated by Jquery. Check: $($pgForward).addClass("teach_create_backforward");
$($pgBack).addClass("teach_create_backforward");

$('#teach_create_pageheader_back').replaceWith($pgBack);
$('#teach_create_pageheader_forward').replaceWith($pgForward);

Comment: @clairesuzy: I retract my previous comments -- you are in fact correct. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @Jon , no they are both ID selectors, i dont know why it shows up like that on here.

Comment: @JDAudi: But you are adding **classes** with jQuery. Change them to class selectors!

Comment: @JDAudi: You are not using jQuery correctly. In fact you don't need any jQuery at all. Please see my example at http://jsfiddle.net/jVvVG/ and do the same.

Comment: @Jon check my original post again.

Comment: @Jon , JQuery is making the buttons.. maybe something there is screwing it up

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: inline-block`, and then float: left

Answer (score 0):

the reason they won't float properly is because of the "step 1" text between them

they should follow each each other in the source to float,  one left one right and then the text in the middle should then fit between them

the answer about not be able to float `span`s is misleading.. you can float any element

example:

```
#wrap {
    background-color: gray;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.fl {
    float: left;
}

.fr{
    float: right;
}

<div id="wrap"> <span class="fl">back</span> <span class="fr">forward</span> text</div>
```

#### Update

I have an updated fiddle for you using your own original code: **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/bjyFh/)**

and lastly in your jQuery code you seem to be assigning the same class to each variable/div.. is that right?

```
$($pgForward).addClass("teach_create_backforward"); 
$($pgBack).addClass("teach_create_backforward");
```

Comment: @clairesuzy Nope. Tried. Still sits in the center.

Comment: that's working for me, is the sample working for you.. perhaps there's other tules in the CSS making the rules conflict

Comment: @clairesuzy Check my original post I updated the JQuery thats creating my buttons in those spans

Comment: it shouldn't matter what's creating the buttons if they display plain first then after creation they're not displaying, there's a JQuery code issue.. I've added an example using your plain code to show it's working, and what about the jQuery variables is that the reason after that?

Comment: @clairesuzy , the replaceWith was changed to prepend and it works perfect now. Odd!

Comment: @JD Audi, Odd indeed (like this whole thread really ;))  - glad it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the code.. My replaceWith was causing the problem. I now have .prepend and it works great. Thanks to everyone for their help!